# Value of coefficients of the power series when radius of convergence is "less than 1" and "greater than or equal to 1"

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n (x-a)^n $ be a power series. As "n" approaches infinity,the value of the coefficients "$ c_n $" may or may not be 0 when Radius of convergence R is such that 0< R <1.But when R >= 1, the value of the coefficients of the power series "$ c_n $" must be "0" when "n" approaches infinity.I know this fact,but i am not able to visualize why this is so.I know its an easy one,but still i cant figure it out.
I applied the root test on the power series which gave :

$ |c_n * (x-a)^n|^{1/n} $ < 1

or

$ |c_n|^{1/n} * |x| $ < 1

or

|x| < 1/$ |c_n|^{1/n} $

Thus R = 1/$ |c_n|^{1/n} $

when 0< R <1 :

0 < 1/$ |c_n|^{1/n} $ <1

and when R >= 1 :

1/$ |c_n|^{1/n} $ >=1

I know these facts.But i am not able to derive what i asked in the question through these facts.i tried "ratio test" too,but to no avail there too.Can someone help me out to understand how to come to the conclusion.Some hint or link will also do.I was not able to find any link based on this particular fact.Thanks.

Comment: No real number is less then one, and greater then or equal to one.

Comment: here "R" denotes radius of convergence and not real number.

Comment: Your radius of convergence is a real number, your title makes no sense

Comment: R for a power series can lie anywhere between 0 and infinity,i.e,it is a +ve real number.and coefficient is the value of $ c_n $ for a particular R. I have taken 2 cases.one when R<1 and second when R>=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 69 - Theorem 3.39 - Rudin - Principles of Mathematical Analysis

For any power series $\sum c_n z^n$ the radius of convergence is the following formula:

$\displaystyle R=\frac{1}{\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{limsup}}\ \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}$

Note that limsups always exist. Also another interesting fact is that:

$\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{liminf}}\ \frac{|c_{n+1}|}{|c_n|}\le \underset{n\to\infty}{\text{liminf}}\ \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}\le \underset{n\to\infty}{\text{limsup}}\ \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}\le \underset{n\to\infty}{\text{limsup}}\ \frac{|c_{n+1}|}{|c_n|}$

This means that if the "ratio test" works then the "root test" will work as well and will have the same limit, and that the reciprocal of that limit will be the radius of convergence. In general the "root test" is better than the "ratio test".